# Gate drive for IRF540N using Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I am trying to build a prototype for the WPT system seen in the figure below. The MOSFET I am using is an IRF540N (source connected to ground) at a switching frequency of 1MHz and is being modelled by an ideal switch.

My question is, can I use an Arduino UNO as the gate signal to switch the MOSFET with a 1MHz, 50% duty cycle square wave? My knowledge of timers/interrupts is essentially non-existent so full code/explanation is extremely helpful.

I am currently using a signal generator to generate the square wave. The current supplied by the signal generator is not enough to charge the internal capacitance's of the MOSFET so I am passing the signal through a TC4427M chip.

Please help me. Any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Since you are at it, you might want to add that transistor to your ltspice and simulate with a pulse source the signal generated by the arduino (with proper rise/fall times and output impedances and voltages).

Answer (score 1):

I have to run atm so I'll add to this answer later, but yes it is possible to make the arduino switch that fast. An issue to be aware of though is the capacitance of your mosfet. The IRF540N has a gate capacitance of 14nC, so you switching at 1MHz means that you might have to be wary of how much current it will draw. A quick calculation shows that the impedance will be on the order of 10's of ohms, which means the current will be very high (this might be wrong though, I'll double check it later today), which could damage your arduino.